# How to batch identify and keyword bracketed photos?

Tags: lightroom, metadata, bracketing, exiftool, keywords

I would like to batch identify and keyword photos that have been shot with the bracket mode on the Fuji XT2 (although I'm sure this applies to other Fuji cameras) to potentially use in HDRs. When I looked at the EXIF data of one of the files I got the following:

[image: Efix data:]

The field is "Exposure Mode" and the Value is "Auto Bracket".

I would like to add a keyword to these photos eg "Bracketed" so that I can potentially use them for HDR images.

For some reason, a search in Lightroom does not bring this up.
I'm using a Mac and Lightroom Classic CC. Also, I can see this field with ExifTool but I haven't found a way to batch search and then Keyword photos in a directory.

I have even considered if Hazel or Keyboard Maestro can help but I'm getting out of my depth. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may take some tweaking to get right, but the command with exiftool would be something like:

`exiftool -if '$ExposureMode eq "Auto Bracket"' '-Subject+=Bracketed' DIR`

Replace DIR with the directory you wish to process. This command creates backup files.  Add `-overwrite_original` to suppress the creation of backup files.  Add `-r` to recurse into subdirectories.

This checks to see if the `ExposureMode` tag is exactly equal to `Auto Bracket`.  If so, then it will add `Bracketed` to the keywords of the file.